# Windows equivalent to a fuse mounted squashfs

Tags: windows, filesystems

Is there a Windows equivalent to a [linux] squashfs archive mounted with FUSE?

A .CAB file packages a directory, but it is then only possible to extract individual files rather than have true file-like operations.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7+ can natively mount .iso images, and Windows 10 .vhdx disk images (although I think the latter needs admin rights).

Other than that, only third-party programs support attaching archives at filesystem level, and they generally need administrator rights to install. (CD drive emulation is the most common kind.)

Comment: what would be a good search term to help find a suitable third-party program or library?

Comment: Not sure as Windows doesn't even have a _framework_ like FUSE that'd allow for unprivileged filesystems in the first place (and third-party FUSE alternatives like Dokan of course need admin rights first...)